# Which open source license should I use to allow forks but oblige people to credit me?

Tags: mit

I have several open source projects. I'm fine with people making forks or using them as pluings/libraries for their commercial products. I only want to make sure that I will be credited as the original author. Will the MIT license suffice?

Comment: Do you have a specific form you want this credit to take, or is preservation of your copyright notices enough?

Comment: Check out https://choosealicense.com